# Apply function on pandas DataFrame, 2 loops where outer loop is axis = 1 and inner loop is axis = 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and have a problem. Please only point me towards the right direction rather than telling me the answer.

```
df = 
idx A B
0 21 45
1 43 76
2 32 67
3 92 55
4 11 82
```

For each row in A, I want to find the difference between that and ALL elements in B. Then move onto the next row of A, and again, find the difference between that and all element in B, and so on.

Please give me some ideas as to how I can tackle this problem. Thank you in advance.

Joe

Comment: Hi, Joe! Welcome to stackoverflow. It would help tremendously if you can provide an output dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use numpy broadcast feature to do this like below

- df.A.values and df.B.values gives numpy array of each column
- (df.A.values - df.B.values[:,np.newaxis]) will give difference between each pair of value in A and B as matrix

```py
pd.DataFrame((df.A.values - df.B.values[:,np.newaxis]), 
              columns = [f"diff_{val}" for val in df.A])
```

**Result**

```
diff_21 diff_43 diff_32 diff_92 diff_11
0   -24 -2  -13 47  -34
1   -55 -33 -44 16  -65
2   -46 -24 -35 25  -56
3   -34 -12 -23 37  -44
4   -61 -39 -50 10  -71
```